# If I already defined div, defined its class, id, etc. can I later (somehow) add onclick="myFunction()"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I mean, can I add it later on, like after I closed that div?

If I can't add it in HTML, can I add that in CSS or JS? The thing is that I created website with Wordpress and Elementor.

And **I can't  edit page as HTML** (edit source of html code), but **I can add HTML code or CSS code or JS code**.

So I want myFunction() to get runned when someone click on div which id is "e-title-2451".

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<div id="e-title-2451">click on e-title-2451</div>
<script>
const myDiv = document.querySelector("#e-title-2451")
myDiv.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
function myFunction() {
  alert('something happened')
}
</script>
```

You can try something like:

```
const myDiv = document.querySelector("#e-title-2451")
myDiv.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your code and nothing happens. I must be doing something wrong. Let me explain what I did: 1. I created myFunction(). 2. I opened inspect element and edited HTML code, added onclick="myFunction()" and everything worked fine. But that isn't permanent change, it's only temporary. When I refresh page, everything I added disappears. 3. Then I made another HTML block (using Elementor) and I put your code in between <script> and </script>. And nothing happens. If anyone knows what is going on, I would appreciate his help.

Comment: I updated answer, so you can take a look. Double check element id. Ako ne ide slobodno me kontaktiraj pa da probamo sa čekićem :) Uživaj :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked!! Hvala brate puno! :)))

Comment: Nema zašta, uživaj / dobro je nije trebao čekić :))

Answer (score 0):

**you can use event listeners :**

```js
document.querySelector("#e-title-2451").addEventlistener('click',()=>{
 //the function code you want to perform 
});
```

for class you can use (".e-titlr-2451")